# Unable to switch from Native to Webview on Appium Mobile Hybrid App

Tags: android, mobile, automation, appium-android

I received this error when switching from native context to webview context as my app is a hybrid app. The app was running/processing before and for no apparent reason I am receiving the error

[image: error description]

[image: error 2]

**Text:**

```
[debug] [35m[W3C (992c52d6)][39m Calling AppiumDriver.getContexts() with args: ["992c52d6-f893-44f4-aa26-554a8d3c8369"]
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Getting a list of available webviews
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\mycv21cg\AppData\Local\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s LHTDU17601000834 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[35m[AndroidDriver][39m Not checking whether webviews have active pages; use the 'ensureWebviewsHavePages' cap to turn this check on
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [35m[W3C (992c52d6)][39m Responding to client with driver.getContexts() result: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- GET /wd/hub/session/992c52d6-f893-44f4-aa26-554a8d3c8369/contexts [39m[32m200[39m [90m248 ms - 41[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
NATIVE_APP--- LAMAN NITO?
WEBVIEW_chrome--- LAMAN NITO?
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session/992c52d6-f893-44f4-aa26-554a8d3c8369/context[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m{"name":"WEBVIEW_com.cimb.ekyc"}[39m
[debug] [35m[W3C (992c52d6)][39m Calling AppiumDriver.setContext() with args: ["WEBVIEW_com.cimb.ekyc","992c52d6-f893-44f4-aa26-554a8d3c8369"]
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Getting a list of available webviews
[debug] [35m[ADB][39m Running 'C:\Users\mycv21cg\AppData\Local\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s LHTDU17601000834 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[35m[AndroidDriver][39m Not checking whether webviews have active pages; use the 'ensureWebviewsHavePages' cap to turn this check on
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [35m[AndroidDriver][39m Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[debug] [35m[W3C (992c52d6)][39m Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchContextError: No such context found.
[debug] [35m[W3C (992c52d6)][39m     at AndroidDriver.setContext (C:\Users\mycv21cg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\context.js:57:11)
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session/992c52d6-f893-44f4-aa26-554a8d3c8369/context [39m[33m400[39m [90m258 ms - 298[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
Jul 14, 2020 10:03:32 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '400' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
FAILED: EligibleApplication
io.appium.java_client.NoSuchContextException: No such context found.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

Comment: hi @JamesZ, please see the text on my question. Thanks

Comment: The issue has been resolved. It was due to the app was changed from unsigned to signed and removed the debug apk version.  Now the dev guys created a new unsigned apk and debug apk version for automation.